# What language is being used here?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

I am reading a chapter I found online on how to add AI to a game of tic tac toe. Somewhere in between they have some *pseudo* code fragments like these:

```
to checkwin :candidate :mysquares :free ;; old program
if memberp first :candidate :free ~
[output check1 butfirst :candidate :mysquares]
if memberp last :candidate :free ~
[output check1 butlast :candidate :mysquares]
if memberp first butfirst :candidate :free ~
[output check1 list first :candidate last :candidate :mysquares]
output "false
end
```

What language is this ?
What is it trying to convey ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a piece of sample code of an implementation of Tic Tac Toe, written in Logo, from Brian Harvey's "Comp Sci Logo V1 2e"

http://books.google.com.au/books?id=BmuqURW0G5UC&lpg=PA114&ots=qZctpJejJa&dq=butfirst%20candidate%20free&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q&f=false